# How to combing many vtkprop or vtkactor to form a bigger actor or prop?

Tags: c++, opengl, vtk

I am working on a  qt/vtk application , where plenty of vtk actors / props can be plotted by user based on his requirement. Now there is a need to provide a functionality to combine all the plotted actor / props to form a mother actor/prop. I tried vtkactorcollection , but it stores all the actors separately . Provide any suitable example or point me to related posts.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are looking for a vtkAssembly: http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.0/html/a01164.html

sadly the provided examples are TCL/Py only, so your best bet would be the interactor example given here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/Assembly

**BUT**: this still saves the original actors somewhere and is slow, you can do a transform via the vtkAssembly's one, but its not hardcore fast.
This solely depends on what you want to do.
Maybe you can discard all actors ans simply merge the poly-data?
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/CombinePolydata

Edit: for plotted stuff http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/AppendFilter could work well too (a bit faster then combined poly data filter)

Even though I do not want to discourage using stackoverflow, imho the vtk mailing list is waaay better for vtk questions, since all the vtk veterans linger around and provide best practices for nearly every requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: Here is an example of vtkAssembly in c++: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/Assembly

Comment: In my experience, the vtk mailing list has swathes of unanswered questions too.

Comment: Here is an updated link to the to vtkAssembly in C++. https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Interaction/Assembly/. Unfortunately all the old links to examples are broken.

Answer (score 2):

```
void Widget::loadObjModel() {
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    auto renWin = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
    auto importer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJImporter>::New();
    importer->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

    importer->SetFileName("E:/Garden/Garden.obj");
    importer->SetFileNameMTL("E:/Garden/Garden.mtl");
    importer->SetTexturePath("E:/Garden");
    importer->Update();

    auto actors = renderer->GetActors();
    actors->InitTraversal();

    auto assembly = vtkSmartPointer<vtkAssembly>::New();
    qDebug() << "There are " << actors->GetNumberOfItems() << " actors";
    for (vtkIdType a = 0; a < actors->GetNumberOfItems(); ++a) {
        vtkActor *actor = actors->GetNextActor();
        assembly->AddPart(actor);
    }
    assembly->RotateX(90);

    m_renderer->AddActor(assembly);


}
```